# JSF Clear input on validation failure of other field

Tags: jsf, bean-validation

We have 2 plain input fields (`h:inputText`) each using bean-validation in a JSF 2.3 page.
If the first input field fails validation, the value entered into the second input field should be cleared.

JSF:

```
<h:body>

  <h:form>

    <!-- If either field fails then the other should be cleared -->

    <h:outputLabel value="Enter text that must be lowercase"/>
    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.mandatoryLowercase}" required="true" />

    <h:outputLabel value="Enter a decimal"/>
    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.mandatoryDecimal}" required="true"/>

    <h:commandButton action="#{myController.doSomething}" value="Submit"/>

  </h:form>
</h:body>
```

MyBean.java

```
@SessionScoped
@Named
public class MyBean implements Serializable{

@NotNull
@Pattern(regexp="(?=.*[a-z]).+")
private String mandatoryField;

@Digits(integer=6, fraction=2, message = "Must be a decimal")
private BigDecimal someOtherField;

public String getMandatoryLowercase() {
    return mandatoryField;
}

public void setMandatoryLowercase(String mandatoryLowercase) {
    this.mandatoryField = mandatoryLowercase;
}

public BigDecimal getMandatoryDecimal() {
    return someOtherField;
}

public void setMandatoryDecimal(BigDecimal mandatoryDecimal) {
    this.someOtherField = mandatoryDecimal;
}

}
```

What is the correct way to clear `mandatoryDecimal` if `mandatoryLowercase` is invalid?

One solution might be to use a custom validator which is aware of all the components and then possibly clear the values that way, but that seems to join the fields together semantically when in reality they should be separate.

Ideally a `<f:viewAction>` with the RENDER_RESPONSE phase would be ideal as I feel it logically makes sense. However viewActions are not able to execute at that phase.

Thanks for the help.
Ed